# replace more than one characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

i having a string variable

```
var text = "hello hw r u";
```

And i need to replace 'h' to '*' and 'l' to '-'

hw to do that..

Answer (score 5):

```
text = text.replace(/h/g, "*").replace(/l/g, "-");
```

In answer to you comment below

`*` is a special character in a Reqular Expression pattern, you need to escape it using a backslash (`\`) character. So it would be

```
replace(/\*/g, 'o')
```

See this [quick guide on JavaScript Regular Expressions](http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_quickguide_regex.html)

Comment: we can't do it in a single replace call...?

Comment: You want to match two different strings and replace them with two different strings. I don't see how you could do that in one replace call

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "hello hw r u";
string = string.replace(/(h)|(l)/g,function(str,p1,p2) {
        if(p1) return '*';
        if(p2) return '-';
    });
alert(string);
```